# Reference an environment variable stored in text

Tags: github, docker, dockerfile

I have a file on a server that contains my access token for github. I'd like to store the access token in a text file that is called on when building a Dockerfile

Here's some psuedo code that I was thinking:

#### creds.sh

```
export GITHUB_CREDS mylongcred
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM some/image
RUN ../path/to/creds.sh
RUN install_github("my/repo", "$GITHUB_CREDS")
```

Obviously this isn't working. In theory, is there anything wrong with what you see here?

Is it RUN, or perhaps some other command directive that I should be using to accomplish this?

Updates:

- The credential file is outside of the scope of the build (one directory behind)
- The dockerfile is being run with a call that I can't change directly because it's being called by a jenkins plugin

Comment: Each RUN command runs in a different layer, you could do them in a single RUN command with RUN /path/to/creds.sh && install_github(...   or you could use the ARGS directive in the dockerfile

Comment: Did you try `ENV` directive in your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible solutions to this (however none of them ideal).

#### 1. **Export and run in a single step**

As noted in comments by @STLMikey, exported environment variables will not persist from one `RUN` steps to the next, as they will be run in two different intermediate containers. You can circumvent this by using a single build step:

```
RUN path/to/creds.sh && install_github("my/repo", "$GITHUB_CREDENTIALS")
```

Remember that `path/to/creds.sh` needs to contain something like `export GITHUB_CREDENTIALS=<insert credentials here>` (mind the `=` which was not present in the original file in your question).

**Caveat**: Note that `path/to/creds.sh` will be included in your image and visible to anyone who uses it. This is most probably not what you want. Also remember that `rm`'ing the file in this step or a later step will not help, as the credentials file will still be present in the parent layer. This leads us to...

#### 2. **Step 1 + Image squashing**

Use a tool like [docker-squash](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-squash) to combine all layers in your image into a single one. This allows you to remove secret files that have been added during the build process without leaving a trace of them in one of the parent layers:

```
$ docker save <image-id> | docker-squash -t squash -verbose | docker load
```

**However**, when doing this, you will lose all of your filesystem layers, making the resulting image difficult to push and pull efficiently. Even the tiniest change will result in an entirely new image with just one big layer. This might also not be ideal. Which again leads us to...

#### 3. **Build-time variables**

This solution is discouraged in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/arg), and there's also an [ongoing discussion about this](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13490) in the Docker issue tracker. Use this at your own discretion.

> **Warning**: It is not recommended to use build-time variables for passing secrets like github keys, user credentials etc. Build-time variable values are visible to any user of the image with the `docker history` command.

You can use [*build-time variables*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#/set-build-time-variables---build-arg) for this, using the `--build-arg` flag. For this, start by defining the argument in your Dockerfile using the [`ARG`statement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/arg):

```
FROM some/image

ARG GITHUB_CREDENTIALS
RUN install_github("my/repo", ${GITHUB_CREDENTIALS})
```

Then pass the argument on `docker build`:

```
docker build --build-arg GITHUB_CREDENTIALS=<insert credentials here>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but my question is all wrong. In my case, the credentials are outside of the scope of the build and I can't directly pass arguments to `docker build` because it's done by a jenkins plugin.